# Using arcpy: how to get name and crs of a raster catalog in fgdb

Tags: arcpy

I already have a working script for extracting feature class names and properties (e.g. crs, geo type) from fgdbs, using arcpy. Since I know we have several fgdbs with raster catalogs, I would like to extract their names and crs using the same script, but I do not find the correct statements for this, or I make some mistake.

My working code for fc's is this:

```
layerLst = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for layer in layerLst:
  <code>
```

What not works for raster catalogs is this. It gives zero results though there are raster catalogs:

```
rasterLst = arcpy.ListRasters()
for raster in rasterLst:
  <code>
```

Anyone?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`arcpy.ListRasters` returns a list of raster **datasets**, not raster catalogs. Those are two different things. To list raster catalogs, use `arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type="RasterCatalog")`.